# Filter Blazor Input field

Tags: regex, filter, state, blazor, state-management

I have a basic input with Blazor

```
<div class="file-explorer-input">
    <div class="search"><i class='fas fa-search search-icon' /><input type="text" name="subPath" placeholder="Select or search for your directory..." @bind="Search" @oninput="OnType" /></div>
</div>
```

When I type in characters which I deem invalid (such as "/" or "<") I want to filter those immediately from the search.

I tried to do it like so

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private string Search;

private void OnType(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var pattern = @"[<>:/\\""|?* ]";
    Search = Regex.Replace(args.Value.ToString(), pattern, "");
}
```

Now my filtering works great. The `Search` immediately filters out what I want and is set to that value. The issue is with the state management.

If I where to type in an invalid character after a valid one (i.e. "s/"), it would not recognize it as a change to `Search`.

The reason being, is because before the typing, `Search = "s"` and then the `args = "s/"` but since the result is filtered, `Search` still equals `"s"`and therefore doesn't recognize a change. However, the input still says `s/`.

I have even tried

```
private void OnType(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var pattern = @"[<>:/\\""|?* ]";
        Search = Regex.Replace(args.Value.ToString(), pattern, "");

        base.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

***Summary***
When I add invalid characters, they are not removed from the input because the `Search` doesn't recognize a change. Only when I add another valid character, are all the inbetween invalid ones removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using `@bind="Search"`, you probably want to use:

```
<input @bind-value="Search" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
```

This way the binding works oninput instead of onchange.

Then change your `string Search` to match something similar to this pattern:

```
private string _search;
string Search
{
  get { return _search; }
  set 
  {
     _search = Regex.Replace(value, pattern, "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great. Could you explain why this way works compared to my original code?

Comment: @thalacker Actually I am not 100% certain, I submitted a github bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19299. In my opinion the original code should work fine, I don't really like being limited to only one way to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Years late but maybe this will help someone else. The advantage of this one is that if a non-allowed char is used it will not jump to the end.

```
<input @bind-value=search @onkeydown=OnType @onkeydown:preventDefault="preventDefaultForSearch " >

@code 
{
    private string search;
    bool preventDefaultForSearch = false;
    
    private void OnType(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        var pattern = @"[<>:/\\""|?* ]";
        preventDefaultForSearch = Regex.IsMatch(e.Key, pattern);
    }
}
```